# Databinding in RowDetailsTemplate doesn't work

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datagrid

I have simple Datagrid with binding and this one works correctly and inside RowDetailsRemplate another Datagrid but in that case binding does not work. Can you give me a hand with sorting this out?

XAML:

```
 <DataGrid  Name="datagrid"  Margin="5,0,5,0" GridLinesVisibility="None" CanUserAddRows="False" ItemsSource="{Binding nowy}" >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Expander Name="expander" IsExpanded="False" Collapsed="sw" Expanded="pos"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                         <DataGrid Name="wz" ItemsSource="{Binding flight_list}"/> 
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
        </DataGrid>
```

C#:

```
 public ObservableCollection<flight> flight_list { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<subject> nowy { get; set; }
nowy = new  ObservableCollection<subject>() {
            {new subject(){ Przedmiot = "J.angielski", Nauczyciel = "B.A.Krawczyk", Sala = "120", Poziom = "Średnio-zaawansowany", Status = "Uczeń"}},
            { new subject(){Przedmiot = "polski", Nauczyciel = "zły", Sala = "130", Poziom = "podstawowy", Status = "gey"}}
        };
 flight_list = new ObservableCollection<flight>(){new flight(){From = "Warsaw", To = "Florida", schedule = new List<string>(){"12-02-2013", "12-03-2012", "31-2"}}};
 DataContext = this;
```

Answer (score 0):

First I don't see a connection between `flight` and `subject`. Second you bind row details `DataGrid` items to `flight` which is not a list but a type, according to your code. Anyway if you want to bind it to `flight_list` unless you specify it as a Source and not Path then it will search for `flight` in context of `subject` type, which does not expose flight property as far as I can see. Also you don't need to use `ItemContainerTemplate`, standard `DataTemplate` will do since you use `DataGrid` which is `ItemsControl`

Comment: Thanks for response, I corrected slight mistakes which had showed up during copying but I still don't know how to indicate the second grid to bind to flight_list since as far as I presume it still binds in subject. <DataGrid Name="wz" ItemsSource="{Binding flight_list}"/> ?

Comment: If `flight_list` is really not related to `subject` then like I said you need to change the context of binding and specify it as as `Source` or `RelativeSource` of `Binding` [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.source.aspx). When you write `ItemsSource="{Binding flight_list}"` it means `ItemsSource="{Binding Path=flight_list}"` (in current context) and you need `ItemsSource="{Binding Source=...}"` but it depends on availability of `flight_list`

Comment: I replaced inside Datagrid by <Label Content={Binding}/> and it displays name of class subject so my presumption were right. Nevertheless, <DataGrid Name="wz" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={Binding flight_list}}"/> still does not work, perhaps write me exactly how it's supposed to be.

Comment: anyone can give me a hand?

Comment: How do you load your flight_list? Is your flight_list static or can you create it as a resource? If yes then it should look like this: `ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource flight_list}"` or `ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static ns:myStaticClass.flight_list}"`

Comment: This one ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource flight_list}" works if flight_list in other class and I create it in resources. But second one i do not understand what means ns(propably namespace) and how it's declared from beginning. My concern is that I had flight_list in MainWindow so I was forced to move it to another class so that be able to create it in resources, what's the way out to avoid moving it, to keep it still in class MainWindow.

Comment: In XAML you specify in which namespace certain types can be found. For example `xmlns:myspace="clr-namespace:my.namespace"` and then you can use types from within that namespace in XAML like this: `<myspace:MyType ..../>` or like in comment above `Source={x:Static myspace:MyType.flight_list}`

Comment: I added xmlns:c="clr-namespace:WpfApplication3" and changed <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static c:MainWindow.flight_list}}"/> and still doesn't work, any idea why? error: "Error 1 Cannot find the static member 'flight_list' on the type 'MainWindow'."

Comment: And another question, how can I get access to for instance Label from code behind cause name of it is not recognizable(in this case name "xwc") <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Label Content="Place of arrival:"/>
                            <Label Name="xwc"/>
                         </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>

Comment: You cannot. You name valid is in context of DataTemplate which can be repeated many times. Bind you label to something

Comment: and what with that mistake, do you happen to know what went wrong?